# GCC and TC giving different outputs?

Tags: c, gcc

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("%d", 300 * 300 / 300);
        return 0;
}
```

This code when run on a standard GCC compiler gives the result as `300` but when i run it using Turbo C, the result is `81`. Why is it so?
I understand that TC uses 2 bytes for storing integers, and the result `300 * 300` would clearly exceed this limit, but before it is printed it is again divided with a 300 right?
And additionally what is computed first? `300 / 300` or `300 * 300`?)
What is the reason for this behavior??

Comment: GCC doesn't fail..... look at this.. http://www.ideone.com/Lvbox
y is it so?

Comment: check the size of ints for both implementations: `printf("sizeof int is %d\n", (int)sizeof 300);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before it prints it divides it by 300, but the overflow already happend, since integer literals are evaluated as `int`s, when you divide, you already with the overflowed int result.

Since `*` and `/` has the same priority, the `*` is evaluated first ([since evaluation is left to right](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm))

You can, however, do either `300 * (300/300)` or `300L * 300 / 300`

Comment: y doesn't gcc fail then?? `300*300` must be an overflow even on gcc right?

Comment: gcc uses 4 bytes for int. There's no overload in computing 300*300.

Answer (score 2):

In Turbo C, `int` is 16 bits wide. `300 * 300 = 90000 = 15F90h` 15F90h will be truncated into `5F90h = 24464`. If you divide `24464` with `300`, you get `81` left.

In GCC `int` is typically 32 bits (not sure about GCC in DOS, and other exotic/outdated platforms). 32 bits are enough to hold `90000`.